# Updating table 1 column based upon filtered table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Greetings to my fellowmen of the CoVid world.  I am stuck with what is seemingly an easy problem, but one where spending 4 hours hasnt yielded any results.  I have 2 tables - ProductList (PL) and ProductPrice (PP).  The PL looks something like this

```
Date          Name       Price
2-Jan-20       A          [ ]
15-Apr-20      A          [ ]
19-Jul-20      A          [ ]
```

The PP looks like this

```
Date          Name        Price
31-Dec-19      A           $10
31-Mar-20      A           $12
30-Apr-20      A           $14
```

I need to update the Price col in PL from the Price col in the PP table.  The issue is this. The PP table captures the price change as and when it happens (which is at irregular intervals).  Therefore, the price in the ProductList table would be updated by finding the closest prior date in the ProductPrice table.  It is this lookup that Im struggling with.

Taking the example above to conclusion, the price for the 2-Jan transaction would be $10 (being the price of the closest date prior to the transaction date in the ProductPrice table) whereas the price for the 15-Apr transaction would be $12 (since the 31-Mar price is now the closest earlier date before the transaction).  I have no code to offer since I havent even been able to get off the blocks on this - even lesser come close.

Thanking each of you for your time and interest in offering solutions and advice.

Comment: `"one where spending 4 hours hasnt yielded any results"` share what did you try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `APPLY`:

```
select pl.*, pp.date
from pl outer apply
     (select top (1) pp.*
      from pp
      where pp.name = pl.name and pp.date <= pl.date
      order by pp.date desc
     ) pp;
```

You can easily put this in an `update`:

```
update pl
    set price = pp.price
from pl outer apply
     (select top (1) pp.*
      from pp
      where pp.name = pl.name and pp.date <= pl.date
      order by pp.date desc
     ) pp;
```

Comment: Ok - Im sitting somewhat stunned here with the ease with which you offered a 6 line solution that fits *perfectly*.  This is some serious shock and awe mate.  Thanks awfully!